# Accessing a mailbox with the new Graph API how to estimate cost?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a need to read a dedicated mailbox and read new messages and its attachment.  The preferred way to do this now, seems to be with the newer Graph API.  This requires setting up an azure application.  Ok, so forgive the newbie question, but how can I get an idea of what an expected monthly cost will be?

Answer (score 0):

Taking for granted that you already have an Office 365 (Exchange Online) subscription and Azure AD tenant, neither AAD application registration nor Graph API requests wouldn't cost you anything extra.

As for the application itself, the cost will depend on the Azure service you'll choose it to deploy to. You've used the "azure-functions" tag in your question, so I assume that's what you are going to use. Well, it's quite hard to estimate an Azure function cost before actually running it (do you know the resource consumption of a piece of software which doesn't exist yet?), so I'll suggest you proceed this way:

1. Create a new Function App, be sure to select "Consumption Plan" as its hosting plan;
2. Go to your app -> Function app settings and set the "Daily Usage Quota (GB-Sec)" as 12900. This way you'll ensure your app will not exceed the 400,000 GB-s execution time, included for free in your subscription;
3. Deploy your application and have fun with the Graph API for free;
4. Enable Application Insights integration for your function app and monitor Execution Count and Function Execution Units metrics to have an idea of what's your function approximate consumption is.

P.S.: Please have in mind that other Azure resources you would utilize besides your function itself (storage account, application insights, outbound traffic, etc.) could result in some charges, though I doubt they will exceed a couple of bucks monthly if you don't store terabytes of data as a part of your app logic.